# How to handle fields inside network headers whose length are not multiple of 8 bits

Tags: sockets, bit-manipulation, endianness

I just started learning socket programming, and I'm trying to implement TCP/UDP protocols using raw sockets.

```
    IP Header
    0      7 8     15 16    23 24    31
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |Ver.|IHL|DSCP|ECN|   Total length  |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |  Identification |Flags|   Offset  |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |   TTL  |Protocol| Header Checksum |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |         Source IP address         |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |       Destination IP address      |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

When writing IP header, the Flags and Offset part, the length of Offset is not multiple of 8 bit. So I take Flags and Offset together as a whole.

```
uint8 flags = 0;
uint16 offset = htons(6000); // more than 1 byte, so we need to use htons

// in c, we can left(since it's in big endianness) shift offset 3 bit, 
// and then convert flags to uint16, and then merge them together

// in some other languages, for example, Haskell, 
// htons like functions may return a bytestring which is not an instance of Bit, 
// we need to unpack it back into a list of uint8 in order to use bitwise operations.
```

This method is not very clean, I'm wondering what's the usual way to construct bytestring when its components are of length more than 1 byte and their endianness also needs to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the usual way would be to declare a `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, or `uint64_t` temporary variable, use bitwise operators to assemble the bits within that variable, and then use `htons()` or `htonl()` to convert the bits into network (aka big-endian) order.

For example, the `Flags` and `Offset` fields, taken together, constitute a 16-bit word.  So:

```
uint8_t flags   = /* some 3-bit value */;
uint16_t offset = /* some 13-bit value */;
uint16_t flagsAndOffsetBigEndian = htons(flags | (offset << 3));
memcpy(&header[16], &flagsAndOffsetBigEndian, sizeof(uint16_t));
```